# chat application status is not visible

Tags: java, android, sdk, chat

I was making an chat application and I wanted to show the user status saying, "I am here" or whatever. But it is not visible. I can't seem to find the error where it is. I have reviewed the code many times. The status field is declared at a suitable scope, accessible to the part of the application where I'm trying to display it. I've checked the display logic, and it seems to be correct.

```
Signup

        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String signup_name = su_username.getText().toString();
                String signup_email = su_email.getText().toString();
                String signup_pass = su_pass.getText().toString();
                String signup_confirmPass = su_confirmPass.getText().toString();
                String status = "Yo! I am here.";

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(signup_name)|| TextUtils.isEmpty(signup_email)||
                        TextUtils.isEmpty(signup_pass)|| TextUtils.isEmpty(signup_confirmPass)){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Please Enter Valid Information",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(!signup_email.matches(Email_Regex)){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    su_email.setError("Enter a valid Email.");
                }else if(signup_pass.length()<8){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    su_pass.setError("Password must be 8 characters or more.");
                }else if(!signup_pass.equals(signup_confirmPass)){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    su_confirmPass.setError("Password does not match.");
                }else{
                    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(signup_email,signup_pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                                DatabaseReference reference =database.getReference().child("user").child(id);
                                StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference().child("Upload").child(id);

                                if(imageURI!=null){
                                    storageReference.putFile(imageURI).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                        image_URI= uri.toString();
                                                        Users users = new Users(id,signup_name,signup_email,signup_pass,image_URI,status);
                                                        reference.setValue(users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                                    progressDialog.show();
                                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                                    finish();
                                                                }else{
                                                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Error in creating an account",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }else {
                                    String status = "Yo! I am here.";
                                    image_URI = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/phantom-67d67.appspot.com/o/User_Profile.png?alt=media&token=1a058332-c2bb-4eeb-ad6d-332508dab554";
                                    Users users = new Users(id,signup_name, signup_email, signup_pass,image_URI,status);
                                    reference.setValue(users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                progressDialog.show();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }
```

User adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.viewholder holder, int position) {
    Users users = usersArrayList.get(position);
    holder.userName.setText(users.userName);
    holder.userStatus.setText(users.status);
    Picasso.get().load(users.proAvatar).into(holder.userImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return usersArrayList.size();
}

public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CircleImageView userImage;
    TextView userName;
    TextView userStatus;
    public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userStatus);
    }
}
```

}